# Ruby on rails routing a nested resource within namepace resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a registrations controller which of course conflicts with Devise's registrations controller and instead of renaming  I thought of namespacing  my registrations controller to :

```
namespace :team do
resources :registrations
end
```

which works fine, but I cannot nest inside this Team::Registrations 
I have been using

```
namespace :team do
resources :registrations do
  resources :players
 end
 end
```

The  route helper  I want is  `new_team_registration_player_path` 
or `team/registration/:id/players/new`

but instead I get `/team/registration/player/new(.:format)` without the `team/registrations/:id`.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Given the above routes definition, this is a valid route (as generated by nested resources). If you want all routes of "players" under some ID of registration, then you should defined routes like `resources :registrations, :only => [:show] do; resources :players; end`. In this way, all "players" routes will be made like this `/team/registration/:id/<players routes>/`. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you providing the `@registration` or the registration's id parameter to the path helper?

```
new_team_registration_player_path(1) # => team/registration/1/players/new
```

Comment: Hi I m providing the @registration